# Como limpar o valor do parâmetro para inserir novos valores?

Tags: jquery

```
&fespecial=lanccontrucao&fespecial=novopronto
```

Aqui tem um parâmetro que persiste ao executar o código abaixo:

```
// $("#fe1").click(function(){
// $("#fe2").click(function(){

$("#fe3").click(function(){

    var url         = window.location.href;
    var parametro   = "fespecial";
    var valor       = $(this).val();
    var master      = url+"&"+parametro+"="+valor;

    if( $("#fe2").is(":checked") ){
        ///////////////////////////////////////
        // alert("Checked " +master);
        window.location.href = master;

    } else {
        ///////////////////////////
        // alert("Unchecked " +master); 

    }

});
```

Eu preciso limpar os valores atuais do parâmetro `fespecial` para inserir um valor novo neste mesmo parâmetro que faz parte de uma url. A cada vez que eu dou um click em um desses ids ele insere mais um parâmetro `fespecial` com um novo valor e eu gostaria de limpar o que existe para inserir o novo valor desse parâmetro.

Answer (score 1):

Use o método `$.param` do jQuery para facilitar o trabalho. Além disso, reformule a maneira de obter a url.

Veja:

```
var parametro = $.param({
   fespecial: valor
});
var master = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + '?' + parametro
```

Assim você montará sua url de acordo com a necessidade :)

Outra maneira de obter a url atual sem os parâmetros talvez possa ser feito com a função `split`. Nesse caso, você pode utilizar seu código, alterando apenas esse trecho:

```
var url = location.href.split('?')[0] // pega o primeiro item gerado antes do "?"
```

Comment: Esse `$.param` é quase que um equivalente ao `http_build_query` do PHP :)